# MVC 4 Running fine on Visual studio but showing run time erron on iis. Model is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My asp MVC application runs fine on visual studio. but when hosted on server its showing run time error. The error is because the Model is Null. But model => model.Service is getting values.

```
Error
Line 86:         </div>
Line 87:         <div class="editor-field">
Line 88:             @if (Model.ServiceIsLimitToList)
Line 89:             { 
Line 90:
```

On Visual studio ifs working fine but showing error on running on IIS. The error is because the Model is null while running on iis.

Following is the Code

Model

```
public class WorkOrderCreateViewModel : ViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Service")]
    public string Service { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Property")]
    public string Property { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asset Group")]
    public string AssetGroup { get; set; }

     public bool ServiceIsLimitToList { get; set; }



    public List<PropertiesList> Properties { get; set; }

    public List<AssetGroupList> AssetGroups { get; set; }

    public List<ServiceList> ServiceLists { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public class WorkOrderController : MobileWebControllerBase
{

    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        try
        {
            this.EnsureSessionNotExpired();

            var db = new DataAccess(this.GetConnectionString());
            ViewModel.WorkOrderCreateViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel.WorkOrderCreateViewModel();
            viewModel.ServiceIsLimitToList = int.Parse(this.GetSystemOption("WODefaults", "ServiceLimitToList", conn)) != 0;
            viewModel.Properties = this.GetProperties();
            viewModel.AssetGroups = this.GetAssetGroup();
            viewModel.ServiceLists = this.GetServices();


            return View(viewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
```

}

View

```
@model WorkorderMobileMvc.ViewModel.WorkOrderCreateViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <p>
            <strong>New WO</strong>&nbsp;
            @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index")&nbsp;
            <a href="@Url.Content(" ~ />Content/Help.htm")" target="_blank">Help</a>
        </p>

        <div class="editor-label-dll">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceLists)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @if (Model.ServiceIsLimitToList)
            { 

            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Service, new { @class = "txt", id = "Service" })
             }
            else
            { 
             @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Service, new SelectList(Model.ServiceLists, "Services", "Services", Model.Service), "---Select Service---", new { Class = "field size3", id = "ddlService" })
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Service)
            } 

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label-dll">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Property, new SelectList(Model.Properties, "Propertie", "Propertie", Model.Property), "---Select Property---", new { Class = "field size3", id = "ddlProperty" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label-dll">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssetGroup)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.AssetGroup, new SelectList(Model.AssetGroups, "AssetGroup", "AssetGroup", Model.AssetGroups), "---Select Asset Group---", new { Class = "field size3", id = "ddlAssetGroup" })

        </div>


        <div style="clear:left"></div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is NOT hitting the catch block because of some exception ?

Comment: Have you verified that this line, right above your line DOES work? @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ServiceLists)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in your view which model to use, something like this at the very top:

```
@model WorkOrderCreateViewModel
```

Comment: how did it run on Visual studio then ?

Comment: Yes I did already @model WorkorderMobileMvc.ViewModel.WorkOrderCreateViewModel

Comment: Please Let me know any solution for this issue